# Converting a perturbing Hamiltonian to the following form

Tags: fourier-transform, superconductivity, second-quantization

I'm reading through Tinkham's Super Conductivity and I am having some issues with getting to equation (3.97).

Beginning with the perturbing Hamiltonian the relevant equation is:

$$
\hat{H}=\frac{ie\hbar}{2mc}\sum_i (\hat{A}\cdot \nabla_i +\nabla_i\cdot \hat{A})
$$
We Fourier Transform the vector potential ( $A(r)=\sum_q a_q e^{iq\cdot r}$ and $q\cdot a_q=0$) to get (dropping hats):

$$
H=-\frac{e\hbar}{mc}\sum_{k,q} k\cdot a_q \;c^\dagger_{k+q,\sigma}c_{q,\sigma}
$$

This equation is ok with me physically, but when I do the FT and use the condition that the field is transverse, I get:

$$
H=\frac{ie\hbar}{mc}\sum_i\sum_{q}a_q e^{iq\cdot r}\nabla_i
$$
It is just not clear how Tinkham went from this to the second quantized form and where that $k$ out front came from. How did he end up with this second relation? Is my last equation correct (I'd think so)? Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I guess that you are familiar with the fact that the momentum operator in real space is the spatial derivative? This is what you got here. You can straight-forwardly see that $-i\hbar\nabla_i$ becomes $\hbar k$ by looking at $c^{\dagger}_i \nabla_i c_i$ and plugging in the FT of $c_i$.

Comment: Sure that all works. I do still have an issue with the sum over i though. To get a q in the subscript I'd think we'd need (assuming a lattice): $\sum_r e^{i(k-q)r}\propto \delta_{k,q}$. How does the sum over i drop out? This just stands for the ith particle, and I am not sure if this i (not to be confused with $\sqrt{-1}$) corresponds to a position...